# Marginal Model Plots - R, car package - part 2

Tags: r, r-car

Is there a way to change the x and y axis for `mmps`?

```
require(car)
c1 <- lm(infant.mortality ~ gdp, UN)

mmps(c1, xlab="?", ylab="????????????????")
Error in mmp.lm(model, horiz, xlab = lab, groups = groups, key = key,  : 
formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments

mmps(c1)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should pass the graphical parameters to the plotting function `mmps` and not to the linear model function.

Comment: Yes that would help, edited accordingly

Comment: They look pretty hard-coded. You'll either have to rename columns in your data or edit the `mmps` function.